# Convert Audio blob to wav file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

I am trying to convert my recorded audio blob to file using javascript and I need to send wav file in api. But I couldn't convert the file here is my code:

```
let file = new File([recordedBlob], 'abc.wav', {
  type: 'audio/wav',
  lastModified: Date.now(),
})
```

I am not able to generate file of that size. here is the screenshot: http://prntscr.com/noxu5b

Note: I have used react-mic to record blob